# A circle inscribed in a trapezoid; $\angle BCH$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

$ABCD: AB ||CD, AB>CD, AD=BC$

$k(O)$ inscribed

$DH \bot AB,H \in AB$ and $\angle ADC = \gamma$

---

$\angle BHC, \angle BCH =$ ?

I have tried to show that $\triangle BCH$ is isosceles, but when I made the diagram, I noticed that it isn't. $\angle ADC = \angle DCB = \gamma$, thus $\angle DAB = \angle ABC = 180^\circ - \gamma$. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: If the circle is inscribed in the trapezoid, it must touch all sides. $CD$ must be tangent to the circle.

Comment: Andrei, sorry, it's my fault. In my notebook I've made the correct diagram but I still can't show that this triangle is isosceles. I will upload the new one tomorrow. Can you explain to me how to show the isosceles triangle?

Comment: Just a digression, it's interesting how a tangential trapezoid can be divided into two pairs of similar cyclic quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 1):

The lengths of the tangents from one point to a circle are equal (due to symmetry you have congruent triangles). Let's call $A'$ the point where the circle is tangent to $AB$, $B'$ the point where the circle is tangent to $BC$ and so on. Then $$A'B=\frac 12 AB=BB'$$ Similarly $$B'C=CC'=\frac 12 CD=C'D$$ Since $A'C'$ is perpendicular to both $AB$ and $CD$, and $AB||CD$, and $DH\perp AB$, you got that $HA'C'D$ is a rectangle, so $$HA'=C'D$$
From these equations $$HB=HA'+A'B=C'D+A'B=B'C+BB'=BC$$
Therefore $\triangle HBC$ is isosceles ($HB=BC$), and $\angle BHC=\angle BCH$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of tangential trapezoid is that sum of the bases is equal to sum of the legs. See [Pitot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot%27s_theorem). So $AB+CD=2BC$, $\frac{AB}{2}+\frac{CD}{2}=BC$. But it's easy to see that $\frac{AB}{2}+\frac{CD}{2}=HB$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood why $HB=\frac {AB}{2} + \frac {CD}{2}$. I am trying to show that if MN is median, $MNHB$ parallelogram...

Comment: @NikolDimitrova: Do you see that $AB=CD+2AH$, $AH=\frac{AB}{2}-\frac{CD}{2}$ and $BH=AB-AH$?